# How to secure admin section using connect-ensure-login of Passport through express router?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack

I am using PassportJS, connect-ensure-login, mongoose, express.
I am trying to redirect user to `admin/error` if they are authenticated but not the admin! I have set UserSchema `user.local.role` where it stores the String among any of these `admin/contributor/manager/user`.

If the user is not authenticated, then he shall first be redirected to the `/login` page (set up at other router file). If the `user.local.role` is `!=` admin, he shall be redirected to `/admin/error`. Else he should access the page as requested.

Note, while saving the `user.local.role` in document, I had made sure to convert the String into lowercase before saving.

**Problem** - In every `/admin/*` page, even if the user is logged in and `user.local.role == 'admin'`, he is being redirected to `/admin/error` with some kind of warning:

```
GET /admin/error 302 729.533 ms - 68
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
```

Here is my routes.js functions:

```
var Setting = require('../../models/setting');
var User = require('../../models/user');
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

app.get('/admin/*', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), isAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});

app.get('/admin/error', sabSettings, function(req, res) {
    res.render('admin/error', {
        title: "You ain't an admin",
        user: req.user,
        setting: req.setting,
        error: req.flash('error')
    });
});


app.get('/admin/settings', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
    Setting.findOne(function(err, setting) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
        res.render('admin/customize/logo', {
            title: 'Change Setting | eduBird Admin Panel',
            user: req.user,
            setting: setting,
            success: req.flash('success')
                // setting: res.settings
        });
    });

});

app.post('/admin/settings/logo', function(req, res) {
    //....
});


app.get('/admin/settings/users/', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), sabSettings, function(req, res) {
    // ...
});


app.post('/admin/settings/user/:pno', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
    // ...
});

app.get('/admin/settings/user/delete/:pno', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
    // ...
});

app.get('/admin/settings/user/verify/:pno', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
 ///..
});

};


function sabSettings(req, res, next) {
 Setting.findOne(function(err, setting) {
    if (err)
        next(err);
    req.setting = setting;
    next();
});
};

function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
 if ((req.isAuthenticated()) && (req.user.local.role == 'admin')) {
    next();
 }
req.flash('error', 'Seems like you aren\'t an admin!')
res.redirect('/admin/error');
};
```

And here are my view `/admin/error/pug` file:

```
   extends customize/adminLayout
   block content

  //- h1= message   //- h2= error.status   //- pre #{error.stack}   
  .center.container(style='margin: 2em; padding: 2em; background:
#e8eaf6;')
      img(src=setting.logo.logo128)
      h1.indigo-text.text-darken-4 Oops!
      h2.indigo-text.text-darken-4 Seems like our bird can't give you access to this page!
      div.indigo-text.text-lighten-4.indigo.darken-4(style='padding: 1.8em;')
        h3 Tweet Tweet!:
        //- h2= error.status
        h4= You should be an admin to access the page
      h5.indigo-text We are redirecting you back to the bird's home #[span#count 32] seconds
      .progress.white.lighten-3(style='margin-top: 3em')
          .indeterminate.indigo.darken-4   script(type='text/javascript').
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var count = 32;
          setInterval(function(){
              count--;
              $('#count')[0].innerHTML = count;
              if (count == 0) {
                  window.location = '/loggedin'; 
                  }
          },1000);
      });
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I did this myself, but instead of placing conditions on controller side, I placed it on my `layout` views, to look something like this:

```
doctype html
html
head
 title= title
 //- link(rel='stylesheet', href='')
 //- script(src='')
 // ....

body

include ../includes/navbar

.row.mainRow
  //- Sidebar

  if ((user.local.role == 'admin') || (user.local.role == 'manager'))
    include ../includes/sidebar

    block content

    include ../includes/rightSidebar
    //- footer

  else
      p You can't view this page because you are not admin
      //- And So on.....
```

Though this is working, I would also be looking for controller side verifications to be in more security, if any one knows do post your answers. :)